# How to compare same coulmn values in different rows having same ID in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table #temp having below data set.

[image]
 I would like to get a result set if pog='Benchmark' and id=33 then matched aged column data should append with Yes otherwise No. .ie, need to get a result as below. same should be for ID=22.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use window functions for this:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  name,
  CONCAT(
    age, 
    CASE WHEN MAX(pog) OVER(PARTITION BY id) = 'Benchmark' THEN
      CASE WHEN COALESCE(pog, '') <> 'Benchmark' AND Age = MAX(CASE WHEN pog = 'Benchmark' THEN Age END) OVER(PARTITION BY id) THEN '-Yes' ELSE '-No' END 
    END
  ) as age,
  pog
FROM table
```

---

I believe this would work too:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  name,
  CONCAT(
    age, 
    CASE COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN pog = 'Benchmark' THEN age END) OVER(PARTITION BY id), -1)
      WHEN age THEN REPLACE(CONCAT(age, pog, '-Yes'), 'Benchmark-Yes', '')
      WHEN -1 THEN ''
      ELSE '-No' END 
    END
  ) as age,
  pog
FROM table
```

Comment: Really thank you for your response. It worked. But could you please help to maintain the age column having 'Benchmark' flag unchanged. Means no need to append 'Yes' to this row.

Comment: I made an edit. Give it a try

Comment: Hi Caius ,hope you are doing good. Could you please help me to do the same if age is a varchar value. I mean can we use a varchar value instead of integer value for this operation?

Comment: I think yes, just change your COALESCE/WHEN in the second version so it's `'-1'` instead of `-1`